# Utilization test for FPS

Tags: real-time, scheduling, microc

The utilization based schedulability test can be used for FPS when rate monotonic scheduling is used. That's what my book says. However, can it be also used under different scheduling schemes (still under FPS)? Why, or why not?

Thanks